# python statsmodels.tsa.stattools.pacf with masked array?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

Is there a general trick to using masked arrays (or arrays containing nan's) with the statsmodels routines? For example pacf and acf?

Comment: without the proper tags, we don't see a question on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the functions don't know anything about masked arrays. The Model classes accept a missing keyword for missing value handling. However, I don't think there's anything in acf/pacf. What would you expect these functions to do with missing data? If you file an issue on github with an example and ideally a reference of comparison results from another stats package, I can look into it.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues

Comment: I guess I would 'expect' acf/pacf to iterate over the time series pairs, skipping any entries with nan's. This could be a bad idea especially if the user didn't mean to have nan's in their data. For example, if you take this approach for computing a covariance matrix you can get a (very) non-positive definite matrix. I'm not sure what  property one would be breaking in the acf/pacf by doing this.